# Cannot boot "No suitable module for running kernel

Tags: boot

I was trying to install sql in Ubuntu 12.04.

But instead of installing i made some uninstalling operation. So while the process is going i closed my terminal window. So now when i restarted my laptop it showing "No suitable module for running kernal found - fail"

My laptop dont have DVD drive. And i dont want to format my hard disk,because i have my family pictures.

I need to recover my files. Please help me. I am struggling for more than a week.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a CD/DVD drive but can you boot from USB?

If so, use another computer to make a bootable USB stick.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/try-ubuntu-before-you-install

Comment: Very much thank you for the reply.I tried this now, but i cant copy the files to any where. Is there any other solution to recover the files?.Please let me know. Once again thank you for your answer.

Comment: Can you copy files to another USB stick?